# jdbc ads emtpy backets "()"on procedure call

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using a stored procedure from my Java app, using jdbc like so

```
String q="{call test.proc(?,?)}";
CallableStatement cal=conn.prepareCall(q);
cal.setInt(1, val1);
cal.setInt(2, val2);
ResultSet rs=cal.executeQuery();
```

for some reason this is returning an error

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '()' at line 1

at debuging I noticed that for some reason an empty brackets set is added to the call

```
System.out.println(cal);
```

produces

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42CallableStatement@223191a6: CALL test.proc(1079,1);()
```

Just in case the jdbc connection has something to do with it, it is

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+DB+"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&noAccessToProcedureBodies=true"
            , user,password);
```

**EDIT**
Ok, this is just plain wierd. I dont get it. Ι changed the call and used the values directly on the string instead.

```
String q="{call test.proc(val1,val2)}";
CallableStatement cal=conn.prepareCall(q);
System.out.println(cal);
ResultSet rs=cal.executeQuery();
```

This for some reason prints as expected

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement: CALL test.proc(1079,0)

But i am still getting the same error

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
> an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '()' at line 1

I really cant get this. This is not my first MySql procedure to use under jdbc. I even tried different jdbc drivers with no luck.

---

**Edit - Solution**
I am not sure how this happened, but the solution was as crazy as the problem. the problem was the curly brackets. For some reason (at least under jdbc 8.0.18) when i removed the curly brackets from the CallableStatement worked just fine.
Again, this makes no sense to me, but since it is working I will not question it much

so the lines

```
String q="{call test.proc(?,?)}";
CallableStatement cal=conn.prepareCall(q);
```

are wrong, and the correct statements are

```
String q="call test.proc(?,?)";
CallableStatement cal=conn.prepareCall(q);
```

Comment: I would suggest to try and remove the semi-colon: it doesn't belong in a call-escape

Comment: tried it as well. didnt help

Comment: I would remove the outer brackets in the string. Perhaps your database is different from the ones I used, but none of the sql connections I've used have ever had those curly-brackets.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am not sure why or how, but you are right. this makes no sense to me. I know for sure that under jdbc the curly brackets are needed when using stored procedures, which is the case here. but removing them, for some reason fixed it. If you want add an answer to accept is as correct

Comment: It was NomadMaker who gave that suggestion, not me. The curly brackets are not required. They are a so-called JDBC escape that is intended to make execution of stored procedures database independent. A JDBC driver should translate it to the right syntax for a database (which apparently doesn't work correctly here), but you are free to use that syntax directly.

Comment: @NomadMaker, sorry, I missed read the poster's name. As Mark Rotteveel mentioned, your comment was spot on. Post an answer to accept it as correct. Till yesterday I knew that curly brackets was mandatory in order for jdbc to understand stored procedures. Thats the way I have been using it for so long. Anyway, you learn something new every day, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the outer braces are required for some JDBC stored procedures, I suspect they are not needed in this case. It would have been nice had the braces been silently removed by the driver. Unfortunately, a standard syntax is not always accepted. I suppose that's the good thing about standards: there are so many of them. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try with
nomosBirths.execute() and q should not have semicolon
If your procedure is a select, use the boolean returned by execute method and use the following to get your result set ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();

Comment: but the procedure is a select statement, which should be read by an result set. If i change it to `execute()` it gives me an error that it doesnt return a result set

Comment: @skaros Updated answer